# Unable to validate dropdown on default value using VueJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

**Overview**

I'm using vue.js with ASPNET MVC 5 web app.

I have below code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Supplier is required.")]
[Display(Name = "Supplier")]

public long SupplierId { get; set; }
```

In database supplier is mandatory

Get list of Suppliers in ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Suppliers = _context.Suppliers.ToList();
```

in view have below code:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

<div class="form-group row">
      <label asp-for="SupplierId" class="col-md-4 col-form-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
          <select asp-for="SupplierId" class="form-control" v-model="SupplierId">
          <option value="">-- Select Supplier --</option>
          @foreach (var supplier in (List<Hashoo.Core.Entities.Identity.Supplier>)ViewBag.Suppliers)
          {
              <option value="@supplier.Id">@supplier.Name</option>
          }
         </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SupplierId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Catalog() {
    this.SupplierId = 0;
}
var catalogModel = new Vue({
     el: '#catalog',
     data: () => (new Catalog())
 });
```

By writing above code, below is my final view with default value and list of suppliers in it.

[image]

**Issue**

The issue is in above code is when I submit my form. It's not validate on supplier dropdown and Ignore it. What I'm trying to do if by default `value="0"` is selected then on form submission it should validate and show me the validation message. Hope I've provided all details according to my question.

Comment: You have `this.supplierId=-1` as default value in your JS code. Which means it is not empty and passes your `required` validation. Why don't you set is as `this.supplierId=null` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What I did is set `this.supplierId = null` and on view `<option :value=null>-- Select Supplier --</option>` and it's solve my problem.